# Función para un objeto literal

Tags: javascript, funciones, objeto, function, javascript-objeto

Soy nuevo en JS y tengo que hacer este ejercicio:

- Dentro de una función pone un objeto literal con diferentes
  propiedades y cuando invoques la función tendrás que buscar una
  propiedad especifica de ese objeto:

Lo que voy haciendo es:

```js
function objLiteral (){

    var obj;
    obj={
        Nombre: "blabla",
        Apellido: "lala",
        Hola: 5
    }
    return obj

}
```

Lo que tengo que invocar es:

```
objetoLiteral (obj["nombre"]) ====> "blabla"

objetoLiteral (obj.Hola)====> 5
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, pero no es así, me especifica que la invocacion tiene que ser asi (obj.p) o (obj[])

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? En [es.so], las preguntas que piden que les hagan las tareas de la escuela, por lo general terminan cerradas y muchas veces con votos negativos. Te sugiero que hagas clic en [edit] y agregues un [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que la función debe de recibir 2 parámetros: el objeto y el valor a buscar. Luego intentas buscar si el objeto tiene esta propiedad. Sería algo así:

```
function getValue(obj, nombreProp) {
   return (obj == null || obj == undefined) ? null : obj[nombrePro];
}
```

El uso seria:

```js
function getValue(obj, nombreProp) {

return (obj == null || obj == undefined) ? null : obj[nombreProp];
}


var persona = {
  nombre:"Einer",
  apellido: "Santana"
};

console.log(getValue(persona, "nombre")); // imprime "Einer"
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, pero no es así, me especifica que la invocacion tiene que ser asi (obj.p) o (obj[])

Comment: Evita responder preguntas donde el OP no ha demostrado lo que ha intentado. Te sugiero repasar [answer]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente pasa un parámetro y regrésalo:

```
function objLiteral (a){

    var obj;
    obj={
        Nombre: "blabla",
        Apellido: "lala",
        Hola: 5
    }
    return a;

}
```

Luego sacas el **obj** de la función:

```
var obj;
obj={
    Nombre: "blabla",
    Apellido: "lala",
    Hola: 5
}

function objLiteral (a){
    return a;
}
```

Invócalo así:
`objLiteral(obj.Nombre);`

**Nota:** si quieres cambiar el objLiteral por objetoLiteral, cambia el nombre de la función 
**Nota 2:** NO PUEDES HACER EL OBJ DENTRO DE LA FUNCIÓN.

Faltaba el ; en Return y un parámetro, y quité el `return obj` y puse `return a;`.

La respuesta era bastante simple: **pásalo y regrésalo de vuelta**, nada más ‍♂️

Fue un gusto haberte ayudado. ¡Ten un buen día!

Comment: esta respuesta no tiene sentido, tienes la suficiente reputación para decírselo en un comentario \\_(°-°)_/

Comment: pero que tiene de malo ponerle respuesta, igual lo va a ver ‍♂️

Comment: Principalmente el problema planteado no tiene mucho sentido, lo mejor es orientarlo a un mejor planteamiento de la posible solución

Comment: Entonces edita mi respuesta:)

Comment: O edita la pregunta. Tienes bastante reputación y tienes ese poder.

Comment: Puedo hacerlo pero no es lo correcto, eso sería sacar de tema totalmente la pregunta. Una edición de tal grado debe de hacerlo el autor de la pregunta, no yo ni otro usuario. Puedes hacer lo mismo que la respuesta de Einer, el plantea una forma distinta el problema y da la solución

Comment: Evita responder preguntas donde el OP no ha demostrado lo que ha intentado. Te sugiero repasar [answer]. Saludos